# Какой контейнер использовать?

Tags: java

Какой контейнерный класс можно использовать как ранилище строк таблицы, в которую часто вставляют в начало и в середину?
Варианты:
ArrayList
LinkedList
HashSet
HashMap
TreeSet
SortedSet
TreeMap
HashList

Comment: Если Вы говорите об упорядоченной коллекции, то что тогда в вариантах делают `HashSet` и `HashMap` ? и кто такой `HashList` ?

Comment: http://antonio-jp.github.io/sampler/javadoc/RiokoDoc/Utils/rioko/utilities/collections/HashList.html

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/d9BIhdG.png

Comment: про HashList - Как Вы можете заметить, это какой-то код, который не входит в стандартную библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Если в программе часто используются операции вставки, лучше использовать LinkedList, так как в реализации ArrayList используется обычный массив, сложность добавления элемента в начало или середину которого равняется O(n), в то время как LinkedList это делает за О(1). Hash-ши не гарантируют какой-либо упорядоченности, поэтому думаю они тут не уместны.